# Find the radius of convergence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Using the ratio test, I get the value $$\frac{x}{(n+1)}$$ Then to evaluate the limit, I move x outside and get $$ x \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = x\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/n}{1 + 1/n}$$ then the  limit becomes  $x\times 1 = x$ so $x < 1$ and $R = 1?$

The answer is supposed to be $\infty$ as the radius of convergence. Did I do something wrong with my evaluation of the limit and finding R? It doesn't seem obvious why the answer is $\infty$

Comment: Forget $x$; it's way too complicated. Forget "+1", it's also complicated. Can you evaluate the $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{1\over n}$?

Comment: $\frac1n$ does not go to $\infty$: the one that does is $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $0$, not $1$, so the radius is $+\infty$.

Comment: So since the limit = 0, then the interpretation would be that the limit will always be less than 1 for any x, so that's why the radius is $+\infty$?

Comment: @EvanKim Yes, the limit is $0$ for all (fixed) $x$, so it converges for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Using the result the radius of convergence (R) is given by, $\frac{1}{R}=\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\text{lim}_{\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\text{lim}_{\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=0$. Therefore $R=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You evaluated the limit wrong , the statement 1/(n+1)  is not equal to 1 since you can't cancel n from denominator since there is no n in numerator. The limit would be 1/infinity =0. And hence  **R** is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}}{\dfrac{1}{n!}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n+1}=0.
$$